# skiprows=[list] not working in Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to skip specific rows in my csv file that I have identified.  Something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', header=0, skiprows=[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8])
```

You would think this would skip the specified rows and only print rows 3, 4 and 6 (assuming 8 was the last row).  However it only skips 0, 1, and 2.  When printed it prints row 3, 4, 6, 7, and 8.  It wasn't supposed to plot row 7 and 8.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It might be a bug: check https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8679

Comment: Try: skip_blank_lines=False

Comment: I get an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_blank_lines' error when I do that.

Comment: what version pandas are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  I used apt-get to get pandas and there was a much newer version in Anaconda.  That fixed it so apparently it was a bug and my code was good.  Thanks.